# How can I add consumers to a Chainlink VRF2 subscription via the Subscription Manager web page?

Tags: chainlink, vrf

When I try to add a consumer to my VRF2 subscription via the [Subscription Manager](https://vrf.chain.link/?_ga=2.27036789.913942137.1659176015-2080342960.1650926966), the transaction completes successfully, but the consumer doesn't get added: the list of consumers for my subscription remains empty.

Steps to reproduce:

- Add a subscription to the Subscription Manager, and fund it with 5 LINK
- Open the [VRFv2Consumer.sol](https://remix.ethereum.org/#url=https://docs.chain.link/samples/VRF/VRFv2Consumer.sol) contract in Remix
- Compile the contract
- Deploy the contract to Rinkeby (Injected provider - Metamask) with the correct subscription ID (as taken from the Subscription Manager)
- Copy the address of the deployed contract and add it as a consumer for the subscription in the Subscription Manager; confirm the transaction on Metamask
- Wait for the transaction to complete, and the Subscription Manager to give positive confirmation
- Reload the Subscription Manager
- The contract should be listed as one of the consumers, but the list is still empty

Here one of the transactions I have used to try to add the consumer to the subscription: [link](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x4cef0747ed55501973b6eae4872b80c51822e2c7e9ef14e0a9e72f01332a4034)

Screenshot of the Subscription Manager confirming the consumer was added.
[image]

Screenshot of the Subscription Manager after confirmation of the consumer was added. The list of consumers is still empty.
[image]

Comment: Hi Fanta, usually, this issue is because the testnet Rinkeby is not stable and the consumer cannot be registered successfully. I tried your steps but cannot reproduce this issue, can you try it again and see if the issue is still there?

Comment: @FrankKong I have just tried again, with the same subscription as before, and this time it worked correctly. Thanks.

Comment: yw, sometimes Rinkeby node upon which Chainlink service relies does not work well, so the service on Rinkeby stops.

Comment: Looks like its a common issue. Had been trying to add consumer for so long.

Comment: @Tarun This is the front-end issue because some service used by the front-end service is not stable and miss some info when requested by VRF. This should only happen in Rinkeby and will not last for a long time.

Comment: @FrankKong thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @FrankKong I started testing in BSC testnet. Saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

@Fanta Instead of manually using the ui from  vrf.chain.link, you should be able to programmatically  interact with the keepers interface in your smart contract.